# How to add Dreamfactory OAuth facebook login in Ionic?

Tags: facebook, oauth, ionic-framework, dreamfactory

I am trying to implement Dreamfactory OAuth in Ionic app. 
I am following this resource for implementation:
http://wiki.dreamfactory.com/DreamFactory/Tutorials/Using_OAuth

This is the call I am making:

```
$http.post('/api/v2/user/session?service=facebook').then(function (result) {
console.log("result: "+ JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

The log above shows me json data as it itself redirects to the facebook url returned by the call and it just returns HTML for that facebook page.

Is there a different approach I should be using in hybrid/Ionic apps for DF OAuth login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make that an Ajax call (or simply set request header [X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest]). This will return the actual URL that is needed, not the redirected response in html. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: In case someone else come across this issue. Simply set request header as:
`$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';`
As mentioned by @Matthew above.

Comment: @mrvipinkashyap - did you achieve the dream factory oauth login in IONIC if so could you please let me know how did you manage the callback after the social login redirect?